# Distributed Priority Queue, once and only once

Tags: concurrency, queue

**TL;DR**

I have producers, tasks and consumers. I need a scalable queuing system which can ensure that a task can be consumed once and only once, and which can sort the tasks according to their priority.

**The context:**

We have a prototype working, but it's not "scale ready", and today we need to scale...

Below is the prototype "process":

1°) Some customers upload dataset in the database (PostgreSQL)

2°) Each second, an application fetches for new dataset in the database and converts them into tasks.
One customer's dataset can generate thousand of tasks (~500K tasks/day, ~30K tasks/customer)

3°) An application "Dispatcher"

- fetches sorted tasks from the database (tasks with the smallest dataset will be proceeded first even if they have been submitted later + some random value to shuffle)
- performs some validations (check if the task has been canceled or not)
- dispatch the task to the according worker.
  Each worker can process only one kind of task, but it can process thousands of them concurrently.

4°) The workers receive the task, and push the result to the database

5°) A "Monitor" application checks the state of all tasks, and retries any task that needs to (worker crashed).

Today, the bottleneck is the SQL server, I can tune it but I would prefer to redesign it the right way. So, I was wondering if there are some best practices for that kind of process?

It seems I need a distributed queuing system (Kafka?), which can guarantee that a task will be processed once and only once, but which will also manage priority.